# How to retrieve multiple fields for a page using Facebook Business SDK

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-sdk

The recent changes announced by Facebook (e.g. April 24 and [May 1, 2018](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-business-sdk/)) have resulted in us looking at the Facebook Business SDK, which from what I can tell is a descendent of the Facebook Marketing/Facebook Ads API.

Facebook points one to their various gems on Github but most of the examples reference managing Ads and Campaigns. For example the [facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk).

Using their test.rb example from [Facebook's Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/business-sdk/getting-started/#ruby) page, I was able to cobble together the following test. As you can see below, it appears each method call to retrieve a value of a field appears to result in a separate API call (or at least some form of network access):

```
1 > FacebookAds.configure do |config|
2 >       config.access_token = '<deleted>'
3?>     config.app_secret = '<deleted>'
4?>   end
 => #<FacebookAds::Config:0x007fd1f453ade0 @access_token="<deleted>", @app_secret="<deleted>"> 

5 >   page = FacebookAds::Page.get('125200950858892', "about,fan_count,impressum,username")
 => #<FacebookAds::Page {:id=>"125200950858892"}> 

6 > page.__all_fields
 => #<Set: {:about, :fan_count, :impressum, :username, :id}> 

7 > page.about
 => "Brandle® delivers social media security & brand protection.  It's the easiest way to Discover, Inventory, Monitor & Patrol your social presence!" 

# Turn wifi off

8 >   page.username
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

# Turn wifi on

9 >   page.username
 => "BrandleSystem"
```

The Graph API itself makes retrieving multiple fields for a Page (node) very easy, so I don't understand why the new SDK seems to be so inefficient (or at least poorly documented) on its face.

I think I'm missing something fairly obvious. There is a Batch API but I would assume that is more for retrieving multiple pages at a time, rather than retrieving multiple fields of a single page.

I'm hoping someone else has figured this out.

Thank you.

PS: If anyone has the reputation points, which I lack, I think this thread should have `facebook-business-sdk` and `facebook-ruby-business-sdk` as tags.

Comment: I'm going to add this as a comment because I don't think it fully answers the question but I just came across `to_hash`, which seems to get all the data after at least one field has been access. `page.to_hash => {:id=>"125200950858892"}`. Run `page.about`
 and then `page.to_hash` returns `{:id=>"125200950858892", :about=>"Brandle® delivers....", :fan_count=>506, :username=>"BrandleSystem"}`

Comment: FWIW, I did post similar question and follow-up over in the Facebook Developer Community on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1762976653745841/

Comment: There is an issue open for the facebook-ruby-business-sdk requesting more documentation. It's been open since July of 2017: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is *an* answer but not necessary *the* answer. I think there still has to be a better answer but here is what we have discerned.

Every time a call is made to one of the methods that returns an individual field, a call to the API is made. You can see from the values returned by `page.last_api_response.headers["date"]`. However, once the first field is retrieved, all fields are available and can be retrieved via a call to `page.attributes` or `page.to_hash`.

```
006 >   page = FacebookAds::Page.get('125200950858892', "about,username,name,impressum,verification_status")
 => #<FacebookAds::Page {:id=>"125200950858892"}> 
007 > page.last_api_response
 => nil 
008 > page.attributes
 => {:id=>"125200950858892"} 

010 >   page.username
 => "BrandleSystem" 
012 > page.attributes
 => {:id=>"125200950858892", :about=>"Brandle® delivers social media security & brand protection.  It's the easiest way to Discover, Inventory, Monitor & Patrol your social presence!", :username=>"BrandleSystem", :name=>"Brandle", :verification_status=>"not_verified"} 
013 > page.last_api_response.headers["date"]
 => "Tue, 08 May 2018 03:19:12 GMT" 

015 >   page.name
 => "Brandle" 
017 > page.attributes
 => {:id=>"125200950858892", :about=>"Brandle® delivers social media security & brand protection.  It's the easiest way to Discover, Inventory, Monitor & Patrol your social presence!", :username=>"BrandleSystem", :name=>"Brandle", :verification_status=>"not_verified"} 
018 > page.last_api_response.headers["date"]
 => "Tue, 08 May 2018 03:20:02 GMT" 

020 >   page.to_hash
```

=> {:id=>"125200950858892", :about=>"Brandle® delivers social media security & brand protection.  It's the easiest way to Discover, Inventory, Monitor & Patrol your social presence!", :username=>"BrandleSystem", :name=>"Brandle", :verification_status=>"not_verified"}

It would be nice if there was a more direct way to retrieve the attributes but that has not come to light yet.